# which operation is more expensive in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am performing two operations which are following can you tell me which operation is more performant and why? consider there is an index on `_id` field and `isdelete` is true already

```
SomeModel.updateOne({ _id, isDelete: false },{ isDelete: true });
```

&

```
SomeModel.updateOne({ _id},{ isDelete: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query, in the filter clause, you are implicitly specifying an AND condition. So optimizer has to scan both '_id' AND 'isDelete' fields

In your second query optimizer will scan only the '_id' index and perform the update operation. If your use-case doesn't need both fields to be validated, 2nd query will be good choice